# How to deploy my own Tensor flow text classification Model to an android app?

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, deployment, text-classification

I have created my own **Emotion classification model** for **Urdu Language Text**. Now I want to deploy that model to android app. As we know **tensor flow** offers to deploy **ML model** to an android app, but I do not understand how to deploy my own model.

However, I have looked **tensor flow** documentation but I do not understand the workflow of it properly. Does anyone know how to deploy? Anyone help?

Comment: This [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/spam-classification-in-android-with-tensorflow-lite-cde417e81260) may help you.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal thanks but their is a problem to convert my model to tflite file

Comment: Share their error in the question along with the code.